# Unable to compile class for JSP:Tomcat 9

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using the latest TomCat version and I've recently installed Eclipse Java EE version so it's also the latest version.
Btw I do have the latest version of **JAVA SE** (JDK).

This is my class:

```
    package jsp.demo;

public class ClassForJSP {

    public static String lowerCase(String data) {
        return data.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

So this is my really simple jsp code:

```
<%@page import="jsp.demo.ClassForJSP"%>
<html>
<body>
    Let's make THIS STATEMENT lower case: <%= ClassForJSP.lowerCase("THIS STATEMENT") %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class
>   for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [D:\Java
>   Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jspdemo\org\apache\jsp\callJavaClass_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. jsp.demo.ClassForJSP resolves to a
>   package
>
> An error occurred at line: [4] in the jsp file: [/callJavaClass.jsp]
>   ClassForJSP cannot be resolved 1: <%@page
>   import="jsp.demo.ClassForJSP"%> 2:  3:  4:    Let's make
>   THIS STATEMENT lower case: <%= ClassForJSP.lowerCase("THIS STATEMENT")
>   %> 5:  6:
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:473)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.14

Answer (score 0):

This message is telling:

```
Only a type can be imported. jsp.demo.ClassForJSP resolves to a package
```

The source code of your Java class indicates that the package is `jsp.demo`.  But at runtime, the JSP compiler has found a package (i.e. a directory on the classpath) whose name is `jsp.demo.ClassForJSP`.

Clearly, something is wrong with the classpath ... and the JSP compiler has raised a red flag.

How come?

- Maybe you are using a "stale" JAR file in the webapp deployed to the server?
- Maybe you have missed a build or deployment step?
- Maybe you have manually assembled the JAR file, or the WAR file that contains it, and have gotten the structure wrong?
- Maybe you are doing this "live" on the Tomcat server, and you have copied a ".class" file to the wrong place?
- Possibly something else?

You will need to look at all of these possibilities yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just reinstalled jdk and eclipse all over again and now it's working