# Unable to compile class for JSP within Eclipse. Apache-Tomcat 9.0.27

Tags: java, jsp

I am doing a course in Udemy, JSP, Servlets and JDBC for Beginners: Build a Database App and encounter this issue with my Tomcat 9.0.27, XAMPP and Eclipse. I am unsure what or where is the error and I have already done a custom package which was instructed:

**Java Package + Java Class File**

```
package com.jspdemo.jsp;

public class FunUtils {

    public static String makeItLower(String data) {
        return data.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**JSP File**

```
<%@ page import="com.jspdemo.jsp.*" %>

<html>

<body>

Let's have some fun: <%= FunUtils.makeItLower("FUN FUN FUN") %>

</body>

</html>
```

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [7] in the jsp file: [/fun-test.jsp]
>   FunUtils cannot be resolved 4:  5:  6:  7: Let's have some fun:
>   <%= FunUtils.makeItLower("FUN FUN FUN") %> 8:  9:  10:
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:519)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

All the previous practice of JSP went smoothly (JSP Hello World, JSP
Expressions, JSP Scriptlets, JSP Declaration tests) until I had to
create a Java Class inside a Java Package and needing to import it
into my JSP File.

Why is there an error on line 7? I thought it was connected if I have
created a new package and a new Java class within the project folder
itself? I even imported the Java Class into the JSP File like so <%@ page import="com.jspdemo.jsp.*" %>. What exactly am I missing because the instructor was able towent through with it. Also, how do I prevent this in the future?
Thanks!

Edit: By the way, I saw a similar situation which was 10 months back [Unable to compile class for JSP:Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338873/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsptomcat-9) and I tried restarting XAMPP, Apache-Tomcat, Eclipse and all of it doesn't work either. I doubt the classpath is wrong for I have followed it step by step too.

Edit 2: I even reinstalled JDK and Eclipse like the person in the link who apparently had resolved the issue, still no bueno for me. JDK 13.0.1 and Eclipse 2019-093.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay guys, apparently the tutorial skipped a step or something. Apparently I have to "Build" the "Project" before I could run it and it shows its output as intended. Problem solved!